# Flask file not updated on Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a simple Flask server. What happens is that a user first uploads a music file to my server (mp3), my server processes this file, creates a new **results** file (MusicXML) and then I render that file on the browser.

Here is my Flask routing:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template('index.html', request="GET")
  else:
    file = request.files['file']
    handle_file(file)
    return render_template('index.html', request="POST")

@app.route('/mxl')
def mxl():
  return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'piece.mxl')

def handle_file(file):
  filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
  filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
  file.save(filepath)
  pitches = mir.transcribe(filepath)
  os.remove(filepath)
```

So here we can see that firstly, a user visits in `'/'`. Then the music file is uploaded (`POST` method), and `handle_file()` gets called. This calls `mir.transcribe` which processes the file and creates a "result" musicXML file.

The MusicXML file is created and stored in the static folder using the Music21 module. So in package `mir` we have:

```
def transcribe(filename):
  ...
  note_stream.write("musicxml", "static/piece.mxl")
```

When `handle_file()` returns, we call `render_template` with `request='POST'`. Here is my `index.html`:

```
{%- extends "base.html" %}

{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as utils %}

{% block content %}
  {% if request == "GET": %}

     <!-- uploading file form -->  

  {% else: %}

  <script>
    // This is the important part, where we call fetch to obtain the
    // MusicXML file we created on the server.
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/mxl')
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function (mxl) {
        console.log(mxl);
        return embed.loadMusicXML(mxl);
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Score loaded in the embed!");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Unable to load the score!");
      });
  </script>

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--<script src="static/js/record.js"></script>-->
{% endblock %}
```

Therefore, as you can see, after we `render_template`, `fetch` is called.

The problem is that sometimes, fetch does not return the newly created MusicXML file, but a previous version of it. However, if I go to my `static` folder, the MusicXML file that is contained there is the new one!

Why is that happening?

Comment: Did you inspect your response headers (especially `Cache-Control`)?

Comment: This actually directed me to the problem, I think (not sure) the problem only existed when I had devtools open, as I had "disable cache while devtools is open" ticked. Therefore, when my devtools was open, there was a No-Cache in the headers, when the devtools was not, I didn't. How can I do it so No-Cache is always there for that fetch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, you can force disabling cache for all your requests, something like:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.cache_control.max_age = 300
    if 'Cache-Control' not in response.headers:
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store'
    return response
```

or you can set the default value for all static files in your `app`:

```
app = Flask(__name___)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 60
```

Comment: Don't I have to return a Response then? And not use `send_from_directory`?

Comment: I replaced that code with my code and nothing changed. `Cache-Control` in the response header is still `public, max-age=43200`.

Comment: Ah jeez, sorry, my bad, updating answer in a sec!